# Why does .find() always return true?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It seems like jQuery's `.find()` method always returns `true`. But that's not really useful because you have do additionally check the length of the returned object to see if it really exists.

Anyone got a good explanation for that behaviour?

Comment: Possible duplicate of that question about comparison in Javascript

Comment: There's a famous question out there that I cba to look up right now that is about how Javascript comparison is weak, and just because your `if` succeeds doesn't mean "`.find()` returns true". I was half-jokingly suggesting that this is a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Anyone got a good explanation for that habit ?

If `.find()` were to return a Boolean value instead of a `jQuery` object, you could not use it for chaining which is one of the overall goals of jQuery.

Comment: Exactly! Besides, you might see the usage of `.has()` also, for in many cases that might be more handy to check if a element has specific ascendants.

Answer (score 13):

It doesn't return true. It returns an empty set of elements, which is true if you do `==`. You need to check `.length` and check if 0 elements were returned.

Comment: okay but why is that useful in any way ? It's just more code anyways and I can check the length anyways before so why is .find() even needed ?!

Comment: what do you mean? in what way is .find() not needed?

Comment: @EvilP Find() is very useful! Seems like you have misunderstood the use of it, have a look at the documentation. http://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: @EvilP: `find()` is chainable, so you can do eg. `jQuery(element).find('a').hide();` which would not be possible if `find()` would return a boolean.

Answer (score 6):

Example how to check if any elements where matched:

```
if ( $('body').find('li').length ) {
    // at least one li was found
} else {
   // no li's where found
}
```

`$()` and selector methods like `find()` and `filter()` always return a jQuery object. This is so you can chain methods. You could do something like

```
$('body').find('li').add('<p>')
```

This finds all list elements in the body, and adds a paragraph to all. If `$('body').find('li')` would return `false` because it didn't contain any li's, the `add()` method would throw an error, because you cannot do `false.add()`.

Comment: *"[...] would not work."* - Not just that, it would actually throw a `TypeError` (in this case probably something like *"Object false has no method 'add'"*.

Answer (score 3):

`.find()` method of jQuery returns **jQuery object**, which could be evaluated to `true` in some cases. But in fact comparing it strictly (`===`) with `true` will fail (the comparison will return `false`).

This is why **you should use strict comparison** (`===` instead of `==`) and **check for `.length` property when counting returned elements** (this is true also about `Array` objects).

It is completely reasonable, as the jQuery object is only **a container** for elements you have found. It must have jQuery methods (the ones you can call on the result of `.find()`), thus it must not be a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Remember

```
$('selector').find('subselector')
```

will return the same result set as

```
$('subselector', 'selector') or $('selector subselector')
```

One of the utilities of find() resides in chaining

```
$('div table').css('width', '100px')
              .find('tr').css('background-color', 'Red');
```